# Javascript to Move SVG path without JS library

Tags: javascript, svg

I want to drag path on SVG canvas. 
The requirement is not to use any JS library.
Any example will help me.

I know with raphael.js its very easy.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example in pure JS:

```
<svg id='mysvg' height="800" width="800">
    <path id='mypath' fill="#4444ff" stroke="#000000" d="M100,300L400,300L100,0Z" transform=""></path>
</svg>
```

JS:

```
el=document.getElementById("mypath");
sv=document.getElementById("mysvg");
flag=false; //to check if the mouse is currently down?

sv.onmousedown=function(e){
    flag=true;
    x1=e.clientX;
    y1=e.clientY;
    var t=el.getAttribute('transform');
    if(t){
      var parts  = /translate\(\s*([^\s,)]+)[ ,]([^\s,)]+)/.exec(t);
      var firstX = parts[1], firstY = parts[2];
      x1=x1-firstX*1;
      y1=y1-firstY*1;
    }
    /* x1 and y1 now contain the previous position*/
};
sv.onmousemove=function(e){
    if(flag){
        x=e.clientX;
        y=e.clientY;
        t="translate("+(x-x1)+","+(y-y1)+")"
        el.setAttribute('transform',t);
    }
};
sv.onmouseup=function(){flag=false};
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gF8Wd/2/

Comment: Thanks for code. The JS is not working on http://jsfiddle.net/arpitworld/gF8Wd/1/. I can not drag the element.

Comment: Thanks a lot Arpit. I am accepting your solution. But currently event is on canvas, so any where you drag path get dragged. Can we only add to path?

Comment: These are simple mouse events that you can attach to any element. It should work just fine with events attached to path.